# Can't pass query to $resource service

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller querying a PHP script (via a $resource service). The PHP returns JSON. The controller uses the input from ng-model called "userUsername". I can see that nothing is getting sent to the PHP file. I'm getting returned this in the console:

```
h {usernameTyped: null, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function, $remove: function…}
```

**app.js**

```
var userAppModule = angular.module("userApp", ["ngResource"]);
userAppModule.factory("User", function($resource) {
    return $resource("php/login-process.php/:username", {}, {
        query: {method: "GET"}
    });
});
```

**controllers.js**

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, User) {
    $scope.loginUser = function() {
        $scope.userQuery = User.query({username: $scope.userUsername}, function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
}
```

I think I've probably got something wrong in the controller function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost right: the problem is the callback. the first paramater, `res` in your case, is actually the resource object.

You don't need that callback in this case, as `ngResource` is designed to be able to work without callbacks in the common case:

```
function LoginCtrl($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, User) {
    $scope.loginUser = function() {
        $scope.user = User.query({username: $scope.userUsername});

        // Just throwing a watch in here to see what happens
        // to $scope.user
        $scope.$watch('user', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log("user:", newValue, oldValue);
        });
    }
}
```

You'll see one entry show up immediately in console, that's the empty data that the `$resource` will assign to your scope object.

When the data eventually comes back from the server, it will be assigned to the `$scope.user` variable, and you should see a second entry to the console with the data from the server response.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm still getting something similar to what I had before. In the console I'm now getting:
`user: 
h {$get: function, $save: function, $query: function, $remove: function, $delete: function}
h {$get: function, $save: function, $query: function, $remove: function, $delete: function}` Is my service definitely set up correctly to take the query?

Comment: In the end I got this to work, but I had to remove `/:username` from the service.